# Why can't I update a data attribute I'm iterating over in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3azcbye3/2/ that shows the exact scenario I've encountered.

I want to know why when I do a `$('[data-prototype]').each` I can't update the data attribute with `$(this).data('prototype', value)` but instead need to utilize `$(this).attr('data-prototype', value)`.

When a click event later grabs the prototype with `.data('prototype')` it's as if it grabs the DOM value rather than the value that should be updated in the jQuery local variable. As far as I understood `.attr` vs `.data` I would have expected the inverse between the two.

**Edit:** After implementing a simplified version of the event piece in the fiddle, it appears to work as expected. There must be something in my other libs causing a conflict.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Data vs Attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: You have extra `  });` at the end. your code doesnt work

Comment: @RoyiNamir thanks, missed that when i cut out the wrapper that doesn't change the affect of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codes returns the *same* result

This :

```
$('[data-prototype]').each(function(i, element) {
    var prototype = $($(element).data('prototype'));
    prototype.find('label').each(function(l, label) {
      $(label).text('****'); //removed code for clarity
    });


    $(this).data('prototype', prototype[0].outerHTML);
    console.log( $(this).data('prototype'))
    });
```

Yields :

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required">****</label><div id="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name__"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___attribute">****</label><select id="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___attribute" name="ew_ability[attributeComponents][__name__][attribute]" class="form-control"><option value=""></option><option value="1">Reflexes</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___composition">****</label><div class="input-group"><input type="text" id="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___composition" name="ew_ability[attributeComponents][__name__][composition]" required="required" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    </div></div></div></div>
```

And this code :

```
$('[data-prototype]').each(function(i, element) {
    var prototype = $($(element).data('prototype'));
    prototype.find('label').each(function(l, label) {
      $(label).text('****');
    });

    $(this).attr('data-prototype', prototype[0].outerHTML);
    console.log( $(this).attr('data-prototype'))
    });
```

Yields :

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required">****</label><div id="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name__"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___attribute">****</label><select id="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___attribute" name="ew_ability[attributeComponents][__name__][attribute]" class="form-control"><option value=""></option><option value="1">Reflexes</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___composition">****</label><div class="input-group"><input type="text" id="ew_ability_attributeComponents___name___composition" name="ew_ability[attributeComponents][__name__][composition]" required="required" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    </div></div></div></div>
```

Taking the results to *beyond compare* , both are identical :

[image]

Comment: When I console.log within the loop it's what I'd expect it to be, but when an event later grabs `.data('prototype')` it's as if it grabbed it from the dom, which I would expect that with `.attr` because of the different storage locations between the two.